# How to prove $|CD| \geq \ $|AB| in intercept theorem like figure

Tags: geometry

[image: Sketch]

Hi everyone,

for the situation in the sketch above it is given that 
$|PC|\geq\ $|PA|=|PB| and $|PD| \geq \ $|PB|. I need to prove that $|CD| \geq \ $|AB|.

Without loss of generality I am assuming that $|PD| \geq \ $|PC|. It feels like I need to use intercept theorem and/or triangle inequality but I am getting nowhere.

Can anyone help, please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Let $K\in BD$ such that $AK||DC$.

Thus, since $\measuredangle ABK>90^{\circ},$ we obtain:
$$DC>AK>AB$$ and we are done!

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in coordinate system. Say $P(0,0)$.

Suppose $A,C$ are on line $y=-kx$ and $B,D$ are on line $y=kx$. Then $A(a,-ka)$ and $B(a,ka)$ and $C(c,-kc)$ and $D(d,kd)$. WLOG we can assume $a=1$ and $c,d>1$.

Then $AB = 2k$ and $$ CD = \sqrt{(c-d)^2+(c+d)^2k^2}$$

We have to check whether $$(c-d)^2+(c+d)^2k^2> 4k^2$$

Since $c+d>2$ we see that this is true.

Answer (score 0):

Assume WLOG $PD\ge PC$ and draw point $E$ on $BD$ such that $PE=PC$. Triangles $PAB$ and $PCE$ are similar, and from $CP>AP$ it follows $CE>AB$.

Consider then triangle $CDE$: angle $\angle CED$ is obtuse, because its adjacent $\angle PEC$ is acute (base angle of isosceles triangle $PCE$). Hence $CD>CE$, as in a triangle greater side is opposite to greater angle.

Answer (score 0):

Assume wlog that $PD>PC$. Let $C'$ lie on $BD$ so that $CC'$ is parallel to $AB$

Then triangles $ABP$ and $CC'P$ are similar, and $$\frac{CC'}{AB}=\frac{PC}{PA}>1\implies CC'>AB$$

Furthermore, angle $CC'D=90+\frac 12$angle $APB$ and is therefore obtuse, so that $\cos CC'D$ is negative.

Therefore by the Cosine Rule, $DC^2>CC'^2+C'D^2$

Thus $DC>CC'>AB$